# Use Python RE module parse SQL Statement

Tags: python, mysql, sql, regex, abstract-syntax-tree

Recently there is a task to parse SQL statement to check the SQL with some custom specification with Python RE module & sqlparse

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE `student_info` (
`id` INT (11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'primary',
`stu_name` VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'username',
`stu_class` VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'class',
`stu_num` INT (11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'study number',
`stu_score` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'total',
`tuition` DECIMAL (5, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'fee',
`phone_number` VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'mobile',
`create_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'record created time',
`update_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'record updated time',
`status` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'some comment',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY uniq_stu_num (`stu_num`),
KEY idx_stu_score (`stu_score`),
KEY idx_update_time_tuition (`update_time`, `tuition`)
) ENGINE = INNODB charset = utf8mb4 COMMENT 'Student table';
```

And I try to catch this statement with RE use some specification

- fields must have `COMMENT`
- must have `PRIMARY KEY`, and `PRIMARY KEY` must `AUTO_INCREMENT`
- Every field must have `DEFAULT` value
- `ENGINE` must be `INNODB`
- `charset` must be `utf8mb4`

And I use regex pattern like:

```
create\s+table\s*`\w*`\s*\(\n\s*`([\w\-_]*)`\s*([\w]*).*(auto_increment)([\n\s\w()',`]*)(primary key)\s*\(`([\w\-_]*)`\).*\n.*engine\s*=\s*(InnoDB).*charset\s*=\s*([\w\-]*);
```

to group all the key information and process later.
[`[Regex Demo]`](https://regex101.com/r/OcuHDe/2)

But I cannot group every single field information, may be cause the order,
can someone fix that regex expression, or just taught me some clue ?

Comment: I disagree with requiring an `AUTO_INCREMENT` PK.

Comment: Observe how lame the 'required' comments are.

Comment: Thanks for replying, the specification is other DBA's specification, i just try to solve this, and in this case comments are just for test, just for convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: I should note that it is not so good to do everything by regex.
>   Note: You can use multiple steps to validate a string by regex.

So, A start of using regex for it that I can think of it can be:

Step 1: Check whole create command:

```
"^\s*create\s+table\s*`([a-z]\w+)`\s*\(([\s\S]+)\)\s*
 engine\s*=\s*innodb\s+
 charset\s*=\s*utf8mb4\s+
 comment\s'[^']+'\s*;\s*$
"giu

\1 = name of table
\2 = body of create statement
```

[`[Regex Demo]`](https://regex101.com/r/OcuHDe/4)

Step 2: Check structure of body of create command - from `\2` -:

```
"([\s\S]+)\s*
 primary\s+key\s*\(\s*`([a-z]\w*)`\s*\)\s*
 (,\s*unique\s+key\s+uniq_\w+\s*\(`([a-z]\w*)`\))?
 (,\s*key\s+idx_\w+\s*\((\s*,?\s*`([a-z]\w*)`\s*)+\)\s*)+
"giu

\1 = fields info
\2 = primary key field name
\4 = unique key field name
\7 = keys field name
```

[`[Regex Demo]`](https://regex101.com/r/OcuHDe/5)

Step 3: Check fields info

```
"(`([a-z]\w*)`\s+
 (timestamp|(tiny|small|)int(\s+\(\s*\d+\s*\))?(\s+unsigned)?|varchar\s*\(\d+\)|decimal\s*\(\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*\)))\s+
 not\s+null\s+
 (auto_increment|default\s+('[^']*'|current_timestamp))\s+
 comment\s+'[^']+',
"giu

\2 = fields name
```

[`[Regex Demo]`](https://regex101.com/r/OcuHDe/6)

Step 4: Check fields name of *Step 2* with fields name of *Step 3*
        And Check primary key field name of *Step 2* with `\1` of below regex:

```
"
 `([a-z]\w)*`.+auto_increment
"giu
```

[`[Regex Demo]`](https://regex101.com/r/OcuHDe/7)

---

If you want to have any sort of `engine` part and `charset` part your regex will change to:

```
^\s*create\s+table\s*`([a-z]\w+)`\s*\(([\s\S]+)\)\s*
 ((engine\s*=\s*innodb\s+)(charset\s*=\s*utf8mb4\s+)?|(charset\s*=\s*utf8mb4\s+)(engine\s*=\s*innodb\s+)?)?
 comment\s'[^']+'\s*;\s*
$
```

[`[Regex Demo]`](https://regex101.com/r/OcuHDe/9)

HTH

Comment: Thanks @shA.t  ;)  I'll update code later, and good night from CN

Comment: Hi, sorry, there is one more Q, sometime after all fields maybe has different order, like engine=xx charset=xxx, or charset=xxx engine=xxx, how can i fix this, (use ?=) ? thanks again

Comment: OMG! it will be so pain full - plz, check this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/2HM0pp/2) ;).